# BeanItemContainer cannot be resolved to a type Vaadin

Tags: spring, maven, vaadin7

I am new to Vaadin and webapp developement, and just wanted to try [this](https://dzone.com/articles/building-a-web-ui-for-postgresql-databases-in-plai) because it suits on of my use-case perfectly. Thing is, upon building and running the project, I get the following error message when connecting to the localhost through my browser: "cannot infer type arguments for BeanItemContainer<>" (VaadinUI Class in the updateGrid() Method.

Can anyone help me? The tutorial is supposed to run and it isn't that old either...

Comment: Could you provide more complete code? Try to specify actual type instead of diamond `<>`

Comment: I used the exact code referenced in the link - I copy-pasted all of it... And TBH I don't know what type the Bean takes considering the 2 arguments specified in the source code give...

Comment: Fixed it by specifying Company as the BeanItemContainer Type!

Answer (score 0):

BeanItemContainer<> required "Company" as type

Comment: This probably because of your Java version. If you're using JDK6 you have to specify the type. Is it possible your compiling using JDK7 and running on JDK6?.